# org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Unirest

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, unirest

after some work on a spigot plugin IntelliJ itself doesn't give an error, however upon the jar build (when loaded into the server) the console prints an unirest callback error.

The project uses the spigot dependency for 1.13.2.

Code:

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.async.Callback;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Weather extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(this, () -> Unirest.get("https://data.buienradar.nl/2.0/feed/json").asJsonAsync(new Callback<JsonNode>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(HttpResponse<JsonNode> response) {
                getServer().broadcastMessage(response.getBody().toString());
                getLogger().info(response.getBody().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {

            }
        }), 0, 20 * 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're most-likely not shading your dependency into your artifact. What are you using to build your artifact?

Comment: @JacobG. - Intelij

Comment: Then I recommend looking into: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206181699-Include-external-lib-jars-in-an-artifact-jar-

Comment: Could you share the error?

Comment: @Thibstars - https://hastebin.com/huhusuwiwo.cs

Comment: @R_Flintstone perhaps checking your dependencies (versions and dependency tree) could help. You might have an outdated version or a version mismatch.

Comment: Unirest is up to date (according to their official website/docs). I look into this problem  later on as someone (from Jetbrains) said that I might need to use a plugin to shade the jar properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Unirest` means, that the class `Unirest` is not found at runtime. A common mistake is, that you have added the library containing the class `Unirest` as dependency, but the library does not get exported with your plugin. So, make sure, that when you export your plugin, the library containg the class `Unirest` is also included in the resulting jar file.